# Not able to save/write sequence of images into specific folder using OpenCV2

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am trying to save sequence of predicted images into specific folder but its not working. Used below code and its running but not writing/saving the images into "results" folder.

```
save_image_path = f"results/{image_name}"
cv2.imwrite(save_image_path, cat_image)
```

Tried with full folder path also but its not working and error is occurring.

```
save_image_path = r'D:\Medical Imaging\Code\segmentation\results'
cv2.imwrite(save_image_path/{image_name}, cat_image)
```

Tried without extension and error is occurring.

```
save_image_path = r'D:\Medical Imaging\Code\segmentation\results'
cv2.imwrite(save_image_path, cat_image)
```

I am using pycharm IDE, Please suggest/guide if possible.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that folder exists, simply do cv2.imwrite("something.jpg", cat_image) and see if it's saving in  your current working directory. In the second case, you have missed to append the filename after the directory.

Comment: Also, can you please show `image_name` variable in the first case?

Comment: """ Predicting the mask """
for x, y1, y2 in tqdm(zip(test_x, test_y1, test_y2), total=len(test_x)):
    """ Extracing the image name. """
    image_name = x.split("/")[-1]

Comment: Can you please show, what you have in the x in this case then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to spesify the file type ( ".jpg",".png",..) as;

```
save_image_path = f"results/{image_name}.jpg" 
cv2.imwrite(save_image_path, cat_image)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Baris Aktas,  Tried it and its not working.

Comment: Okey, where do you get your image from, and what happens when you run the code can you share the error you get?